# Is there a word or phrase that means something along the line of "guaranteed to be reliable"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

> The product is **guaranteed to be reliable** by 10 years of use by the
>   military.

I can't think of a word or phrase we can use and that means something along the line of "guaranteed to be reliable". Even in the example above, the phrase makes little grammatical sense, because of the "by", but I swear there's a word or phrase you can use to fill in the blank.

> The product is ____ by 10 years of use by the
>   military.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that fits is ***backed*** *by*, but that doesn't mean the same thing as *guaranteed to be reliable*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of anything that is relevant that fits in the blank (without any surrounding changes) followed by a "by". The first "by" is misplaced; it does not fit there. I think what you need is a "for".

> The product is guaranteed to be reliable **for** 10 years of use by the military.

It stills sounds off to me.

Why not rephrase it? This is one option:

> This product comes with a guarantee that it will be fully usable by the military for at least 10 years.

You could say "operational" instead of "usable". A more simpler rephrasing would be

> This product guarantees 10 years of reliable use by the military.

Comment: but it was used for 10 years

Answer (score 0):

Proven reliability.

Proven Dependability

Earned trust

The military has depended on it for the last ten years proving it's reliability